# Linking two DataGridViews

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have two Grid controls in VB.Net Winform application connected to Oracle Database. The first one shows a table 1 with fields (among others) ID and TaskName. The second one shows a linked table with fields (among others) Task. In the logic of the application the two tables are linked (Table 1, Field ID) <----> (Table 2, Field Task).

I would like, when selecting a row in the first DataGridView, have only the linked row in the second GridView but I can't make it work.

Here is my code attempt :

```
    Dim SQLQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM SCHEME.ARCH_TASKS"

    Conn = New OracleConnection(ConnectionString)
    Command = New OracleCommand(SQLQuery, Conn)
    DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)

    DataSet = New DataSet()
    DataTable1 = New DataTable

    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable1)
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable1)

    DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable1.DefaultView
    GridControl1.DataSource = DataTable1.DefaultView



    SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM SCHEME.ARCH_LINK_ROLE_TASK"
    Command = New OracleCommand(SQLQuery, Conn)
    DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)

    DataTable2 = New DataTable

    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable2)
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable2)
    GridControl2.DataSource = DataTable2


    DataSet.Relations.Add(DataTable1.Columns("ID"), DataTable2.Columns("TASK"))
```

Here is the result

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/4713062013102413h1253.png

As you can see, I added manually a relationship between the two data tables but it doesn't really do what i'm looking for. It simply adds a subline in the first grid control.

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/7508382013102413h1309.png

I tried to apply what PeterG suggested but I still can't make it work.

```
    Dim SQLQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM SCHEME.ARCH_TASKS"

    Command = New OracleCommand(SQLQuery, Conn)
    DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable1)
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable1)

    SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM SCHEME.ARCH_LINK_ROLE_TASK"

    Command = New OracleCommand(SQLQuery, Conn)
    DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable2)
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable2)

    DataSet.Relations.Add(DataTable1.Columns("ID"), DataTable2.Columns("TASK"))

    BindingSource1.DataSource = DataSet
    GridControl1.DataSource = BindingSource1.DataSource
    GridControl1.DataMember = "Table1"

    BindingSource2.DataSource = BindingSource1.DataSource
    GridControl2.DataSource = BindingSource2.DataSource
    GridControl2.DataMember = "Table2"
```

Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to bind your grids via bindingsources rather than directly. Tthen set the parent bs in the normal way; with the child bs, however, set the datasource to the parent bs, and the datamember to the relation.

Comment: How to do that please ? or do you have any example ?

Comment: Drag to bindingsources onto your form from the toolbox; set the datasource of the grids to one bs each; set the datasource/datamember of the parent grid to the ds and table as appropriate; set the datamember and datasource of the child bs as per my orig comment.

Comment: Thanks PeterG, I tried to do what you suggested (See the code added in the post), but I'm still missing something. Should I add something else ? Thank you for answer.

Comment: I meant do all that in the designer, not in code. But also I have just spotted that you aren't using strongly-typed datasets - using these gives you much better design-time support for binding and for designing your grid columns etc. Also, in the code you added you should be assigning the grids' datasource to the bs, not to the datasource of the bs.

Comment: Got your point ! Actually I'm trying to design a canvas that will be used to display any Parent table data with its child details. A kind of generic form. That's why I'm trying to do it programmatically.

Comment: Do you have any sample code please ? Thanks

Comment: ok but I would recommend that you get your head round the designer first then extrapolate from there to the programmatic version. The basics are descrobed in this walkthrough I think: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx